# How do I restart a frozen screen in Ubuntu without losing any open windows?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg

I had a device running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS have its screen freeze. Generally I have simply jumped onto an available tty, i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and executed the command `/etc/init.d/lightdm restart` or `service lightdm restart`. This however kills everything I have open. How do I avoid this?

Comment: You can't achieve this. It is lightdm which displays/manages windows in x system.

Comment: This will also kill whatever you have open, but once upon a time ctrl-alt-backspace would restart X. That's easier than switching to a TTY, logging in, and asking X to restart itself.  I'm not sure if it still works though.

Comment: @Douglas B. Staple - It doesn't work with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Not sure whether it still works with other distributions or whether this is specific to Unity.

Comment: There may be some way to replace the window manager while running. (It's possible with the GNOME-Shell at least, or with the i3 window manager so there could be some way).

Comment: @FSMaxB - Could you please elaborate on how this can be achieved using the Gnome-Shell or i3 Window Manager?

Comment: If you manage to start a terminal inside the frozen gnome-shell (may work even if you don't see it) you can type in "gnome-shell --replace" and [Alt]+[F2] "r" and [Enter] does the same (depends on "how frozen" your system is and what exactly is frozen [Xorg, Window Manager etc.]). When using i3 (most people don't want to use it as it is a tiling window manager and very minimalistic [the only builtin tool is an application starter]) you need to press [mod]+[shift]+[r] where mod is either [Alt] or the windows key (sometimes called mod4 or super key), depending on your prior settings.

Comment: @FSMaxB - Thanks. I take it there is no similar method with Unity?

Comment: I have no idea. I never ever used unity.

Comment: @FSMaxB - How would you start a terminal inside of a frozen gnome shell?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I found a better way: Got to tty1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and type 'DISPLAY=:0' then 'export DISPLAY' and then 'gnome-shell --replace'. This way you can start programs running on the X-Server on tty7 from tty1 and thereby restart the GNOME shell without having to be able to start a terminal inside the frozen GNOME shell

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** According to Brenden's comment, this might be outdated and not work anymore with newer versions of Ubuntu. Also please be prepared that you might lose your open windows.

Now I got it for Unity (I just replaced my GNOME shell with unity without logging out or closing windows):

1. Go to tty1 [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F1]
2. Type in `DISPLAY=:0` so that programs know on what port to find the X-Server
3. `export DISPLAY`
4. `unity --replace` or `gnome-shell --replace` (you can also replace GNOME-Shell by unity or Unity by the GNOME-Shell)

This only works if not the X-Server or GNOME is frozen but only Unity or the GNOME-Shell.

How it works:
The communication between programs and the X-Server for displaying their UI is working over a network socket. This normally is at "localhost:0" short ":0". By setting the DISPLAY variable, the programs know where to find the X-Server to communicate with it, so programs are displayed on the X-Server on tty7 even if the program is running on tty1.

The content of windows is managed by the X-Server whereas the position and borders of the windows is  managed by the window manager integrated in unity or the GNOM-shell so there is a way to replace only them without restarting the applications on the X-Server.

PS: I'm just describing what I understand it to be, so please edit and correct me if I'm wrong in some points.

**EDIT:**
For the GNOME-Shell, there is another way to restart it. After changing to tty simply type in `pkill -HUP gnome-shell`, I don't know if there's something similar for Unity.

Comment: That worked like a miracle. In fact it saved me today. Thanks so much. I would be so grateful if you could elaborate what each of the steps do bar step 1. I don't quite understand what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Note unity --help says: "--replace             Run unity /!\ This is for compatibility with other
                        desktop interfaces and acts the same as running unity
                        without --replace"

Comment: Also I found I had to run unity  via sudo to save my windows.

Comment: --replace is deprecated and does nothing and this solution will restart your session meaning you lose all of your windows :(

Comment: Still works in 2018

Answer (score 0):

If your screen is frozen, but mouse is still moving (however no result on left-click) - try

1. close suspicious (in terms of locking too much memory) apps;

You can use keyboard alt-tab to select and alt-f4 to close.

2. right-click anywhere.

Dunno why it happens and why right-click works, but at least it works.