# Windows in Gnome on Ubuntu 10.10 are frozen. What can I do?

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, gnome

I used to see the link below and I think it would be helpful but the problem is I can't run any of TTY.

[How do I restart a frozen screen in Ubuntu without losing any open windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/570194/how-to-i-restart-a-frozen-screen-in-ubuntu-without-losing-any-open-windows)

I'm trying to do it with alt + ctrl + F1 and it doesn't work and honestly I even can't say if it ever been worked before. It already occured one time about one month ago and fixed after 3 hours of waiting but this time the difference is that the cursor is moving and the clock is working right. Moreover all system monitor indicators shows current state of hardware so it seems that processor disc ram and swap are also working. It happened during moving a terminal window to another part of workspace which is displayed on second monitor. And, what is strange, I can see mini dialog box with the resolution of the window that I have never seen before. Trying to unplug the second monitor didn't help. What can I do to unfreeze it and don't lose unsaved data?

Comment: I am not aware of any alternative keyboard shortcut within Ubuntu that duplicates ALT+CTRL+F1

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut SUPER + D made windows (GNOME) unfrozen so in similar cases this should be helpful.